# How to repaint() after clicking a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, drawing

I would like to make an animation of a labyrinth's path. I use drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) and repaint() inside a loop to draw the path square by square.
But it doesn't refresh and only shows the last step of the path like this... : [Maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLB7l.jpg)

Thank you for your help.

```
public class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    private JButton go = new JButton ("GO");
    private Panneau panneau = new Panneau();

    /* ... */

    public Fenetre() {             
        /* ... */

        this.go.addActionListener(new BoutonListener());
        this.top.add(this.go);

        this.container.add(this.top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.container.add(this.panneau, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setContentPane(this.container);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void go() {     
        /* ... */

        for (int i = 0; i < this.panneau.getChemin().size() - 1; i++) {
            this.panneau.setX1(this.panneau.getChemin().get(i).getX());
            this.panneau.setY1(this.panneau.getChemin().get(i).getY());
            this.panneau.setX2(this.panneau.getChemin().get(i + 1).getX());
            this.panneau.setY2(this.panneau.getChemin().get(i + 1).getY());

            this.panneau.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class BoutonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            go();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Panneau extends JPanel {
    /* ... */

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        /* ... */

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(this.posX + 5 + (10 * this.x1), this.posY + 5 + (10 * this.y1), this.posX + 5 + (10 * this.x2), this.posY + 5 + (10 * this.y2));
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: See MadProgrammer's answer in the (one of many) duplicate question. You're blocking the Swing event thread with your loop and use of `Thread.sleep`. One solution is to use a background thread, but a much easier solution is to just use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to help drive the animation loop. This would mean getting rid of the for loop, getting rid of the Thread.sleep and letting the timer's repeated actionPerformed calls drive the animation. It will work.

Comment: [Link to similar questions, some answers with code examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=s&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+animation+thread+sleep+)